# Grep in a huge log file (>14 GB) only the last x GB?

Tags: linux, log-files, grep

I need to search something in a huge log-file (over 14 GB). I'm pretty sure it's in the last 4 GB or so.

Is there a way to skip the first X GB to speed things up?

Comment: `LC_ALL=C grep` may speed it up.

Comment: You will be able to get a lot of speed by picking a sensible `grep` expression... wildcards of unknown length (like `a.*thing`) will in some cases take much longer to evaluate. It may be that you are optimizing for the wrong thing (although it never hurts to search only part of the file, obviously - it may just not be the greatest source of speedup).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I guess you could use [tail](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) to only output that last 4GB or so by using the `-c` switch

> -c, --bytes=[+]NUM
>   output the last NUM bytes; or use -c +NUM to output starting with byte NUM of each file

You could probably do something with [dd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) too by setting `bs=1` and `skip`ing to the offset you want to start e.g.

```
dd if=file bs=1024k skip=12g | grep something
```

Comment: Thanks! you saved me a tone of time! I added the command as i used it to my question. Works a charm!

Comment: Afterwards, you should configure logrotate.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yeah i did. I thought it was setup but it wasn't.

Comment: @Rogier Please add an answer with the solution instead of adding it in your question. This is similar to self-answer: http://serverfault.com/help/self-answer

Comment: The OP doesn't need to add an answer. they clearly used mine.

Comment: @istheEnglishway maybe you can add my `command` as-well (i then remove my update)? its slightly different. I already accepted your answer, and didn't want to add another answer.

Comment: @istheEnglishway: Well, no, they posted a different command.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You need to read my answer, the first comment above and possibly the edit histories before poking your nose in. The OP implemented a solution using `tail -c` which is what my answer suggests.

Comment: But your answer doesn't provide the actual command that implements that solution, which is added value. You could edit that into your answer, or the OP could post it as a new answer. They definitely shouldn't add it to the question, which is what happened. And you definitely shouldn't be throwing around epithets like "poking your nose in".

Comment: It clearly doesn't need to provide the actual command. I would also argue that providing the actual command is less useful to other people that may find this Q&A going forward. Just look at the mess that  [tag:mod-rewrite] and [tag:virtualhost] . People are entirely unable to take specifics and apply them to their own exactly the same but different issue and want personalised hand holding.

Comment: @istheEnglishway, believe it or not having an example make things easier than having to read a man page (see also : stackoverflow documentation)

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas believe it or not I disagree with you. Re: SO documentation - just another write only medium that no one who needs to will ever bother reading.

Comment: `bs=1` will be incredibly slow. Like 1000x to 10000x slower than normal reads.

Answer (score 33):

*I'm just posting this because some of the comments asked for it.*

What I end-up using was (15 GB file). It worked very fast and saved me a ton of time.

```
tail -f -c 14G file | grep something
```

I also did a very rudimentary benchmark on the same file. I tested:

> grep xxx file
> // took for-ever (> 5 minutes)
>
> dd if=file  bs=1 skip=14G | grep xxx
> // very fast < 1 sec
>
> tail -c 14g | grep xxx
> // pretty fast < 2 sec

the `tail` is just a bit shorter.

**NB:** the suffix used `g` and `G` differ per command (Ubuntu 15.10)

Comment: Did you clear the disk cache between the benchmarks? I suspect most of the time in the first one was I/O. The speedup should be on the order of 15×, not 300×.

Comment: @Reid i didn't. But i did run *each* command multiple times. Im pretty sure that *dd* or *tail* will boost the speed significantly over just *grep* (cache or not).

Answer (score 19):

This doesn't answer the Title question, but it will do what you are wanting to do.  Use tac to reverse the file, then use grep to find your string.  If your string only occurs once or a known number of times in the file, then let it run until it finds the known number of occurrences.  That way, if your assumption about where it is in the file is incorrect, it will still find it.  If you do want to limit it, you can use head to do that.  The head command would go between the tac and the grep.

So the command looks like:

```
tac < logfile | grep myString
```

Comment: I came here to write the exact same answer. I'm surprised nobody upvoted yours.

Comment: Took me a minute, but then I groaned at the pun... tac is the opposite of cat.

Comment: I needed to dig around in a *application/debug log*. Because it reverses the lines, its not getting easier to read ;-) However, seems very fast. Never seen `tac`, so thanks!